# Why is setAlpha() not working in RecyclerViews?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, transparency, android-viewholder

I am trying to change the transparency of item-views in a RecyclerView according to certain user inputs.

```
if (quantity>0) {
    holder.itemView.setAlpha((float) 1);
} else {
    holder.itemView.setAlpha((float) 0.65);
}
```

**Changing alpha from 0.65 to 1 works fine when quantity > 0. But the reverse is not working on the other case.** When debugging, it clearly shows going through the line `holder.itemView.setAlpha((float) 0.65);` However, alpha is not reduced. Any clue about what's going on?

Comment: Why weird `(float) 1` instead of `1f` (or even better, `1.0f`)?

Comment: *it clearly shows going through the line holder.itemView.setAlpha((float) 0.65)* when it shouldn't?

Comment: @mTak no. Only when it should do. But it's not making any change in the alpha. That's what I am taking about.

Comment: Explain this: *it clearly shows going through the line holder.itemView.setAlpha((float) 0.65); * this is  *Changing alpha from 1 to 0.65* that *works fine*. Does the debugger go through the other line?

Comment: @mTak Really sorry. There was a mistake in the question (At the bold part ) . I have updated it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem. Instead of changing the alpha of the `itemView`, give an name to your root layout and change its alpha instead, as the recyclerview animations handle the `itemView` alpha animation making it not work.

Comment: It was an old question and the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356316/7594961) worked for me. I couldn't try this however this seems to be a better solution if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anees. I knew it was an old question, but I just had this problem today and found your question. The solution here worked but it removed the diff animations. As I solved it without removing the animation I thought it would be nice to leave the reply here for someone in the future :)

Comment: This is not working, because the itemView is your root layout.

Comment: @KimiChiu I didn't try this method but I think by root view, he means the direct child of itemview. If there is more than one you have to wrap it in another layout.

Answer (score 8):

recycler's ItemAnimator changes alpha during update item process
you can try to add

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) myRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null); worked for me. I was about to post the answer. But while using your method, I could preserve other animations. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was stuck on this issue for quite sometime. Thank you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Remove item animator

In Java:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
recycler_view.itemAnimator = null
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this is the HolderView class

```
class MyViewHolder(val viewHolder: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

And consider this is how your Adapter class looks like from inside

```
// ...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, i: Int) {
    holder.viewHolder.alpha = 0.65f
}
```

Sometimes if your code is `holder.viewHolder.alpha = 0.65f` it doesn't work always!

Rather than that, you may use alpha of the main container just like that

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ... Your other components goes here

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, from your adapter use this instead, it should work in all cases

```
// ...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, i: Int) {
    holder.viewMain.alpha = 0.65f
}
```